# Finding A Non-Arbitrary Version of A specific 'Cubic' Curve

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, conic-sections, curves, golden-ratio

**Please See "Clarification" for more clarity**

I found a curve that I've been looking for; well sort of: The curve, shown in my fig., and **[Graphed Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q3mdpnqzqz)**, matches certain criteria: **1.** Overall shape. **2.** Height. **3.** Overall Proportions (at least to a good approximation). **4.** Position. etc....

Nevertheless, my curve seems arbitrary; I had to force it to do this. So, I was wondering if anyone knows of or can derive a similar curve that matches the above without requiring all kinds of constants to move it around and scale it (you **CAN** use the golden ratio constant, however). Basically, I want a proper function for this, not something forced. Thank you!

If it's any help, $y(t)=\frac{1-φ^{-1+t}}{1-φ}+φ^{-1}$, or something extremely similar should be able to be used as the partial solution (namely the solution for $y(t)$) in a parameterization.

**Clarification:**

As you can see, my equations give a very specific curve (which is virtually identical to the one I want in appearance). What I'm looking for is something that is **'naturally'** almost identical to my curve in every way (really I mean every way).

A good analogy is this: Imagine if you'd never seen the equation $y=1/x$ but you had an image of it and a similar curve; you could probably modify the similar curve until it approximated the properties of $y=1/x$. The modified similar curve is to $y=1/x$ as my curve is to what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: **Note** that my curve is, in essence, a modification of the Tschirnhausen Cubic.

Comment: To be clear, you want a scale and parametrization [of $y^2=x^2(x+1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve) ?

Comment: @reuns Thank you, but no, I want a non-arbitrary version of my curve (a curve very like it).

Comment: Which curve, what do you want **exactly**

Comment: In very short (more coming soon) I want an 'official' version of my curve.

Comment: @reuns Note that my curve is specifically modified to be stretched out and bigger (+ slightly reshaped). I want to know if 'my curve' (really the curve mine approximates) can be represented by something without scaling factors or factors for moving it.

Comment: @reuns Sorry about the subtleties of what I'm trying to convey. Perhaps an analogy might help: Think about the Hyperbola $y=1/x$. This is an extremely simple, elegant thing. Now, imagine taking a similar curve and messing with it until it approximates $y=1/x$ (the 'official' curve), if the approximation were good enough, someone could post it and say, "can you simplify this," to which a person might answer don't you really just want $y=1/x$? Does that explain it?

Comment: So, I'm looking for a curve (very, very close to what I have in all aspects) that is nice and simple like $y^{2}=x^{2}(x+1)$; (though it should be noted that the answer might (or might not) employ the golden ratio constant (0.618...).

Comment: @reuns I hope that explains things?!

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Thank you for the comment. I will. Yes, I do mean that this is the answer for $y(t)$.

Comment: In so far as desmos, it's not different than any other math, parametric equations are $(f(t), f(t))$. I didn't include the parameterized equations directly because I linked to them and put them in the image. Once more, thank you!

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin If you want, you can feel free to edit my post if you want to clarify it and can think of a way to do so. *BTW*, do you personally know of such a curve?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin  (BTW, I'm editing the post now!) You can take out the $ϕ^{-1}$, if you'd like. Once I have the curve (which should be scaled down if you do this but maintain very similar proportions) it  should be easy to adjust it to put it back again. Thank you! (I hope that makes sense.) Anyhow, let me know if you think of anything?!

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I edited it. Let me know if it's any good or needs further work.

Comment: OH, **BTW**, @LeeDavidChungLin the $ϕ^{-1}$ I think you were thinking of (the one in the equation, not the the one in the series) is just there to zero it and has no particular importance. Removing this should **NOT** change the scale. Anyhow, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104300/discussion-between-jinny-ecckle-and-lee-david-chung-lin).